# PostgreSQL: create temporary table, added to main select query and avoid more than one row error

Tags: sql, postgresql

Again, I'm struggling to understand how SQL works. Hence, I'll explain to you what data I have and what I've done so far.

I have 5 tables:

loan

[image: loan]

loan_role

[image: loan role]

legal_person

[image: legal_person]

legal_person_attribute

[image: legal_person_attribute]

legal_person_attribute_key

[image: legal_person_attribute_key]

I want to do a selection of different columns, where the attribute key selects the value column that I want to have. What I have done is this:

```
select l.id as loan_nr, l.country, l.currency, l.principal_amount, l.duration, l.nominal_interest_rate, l.annuity, l.payout_date                              ,
       (select lpa.value as company_name
        from etl.legal_person_attribute lpa, etl.legal_person_attribute_key lpak
        where lpa.fk_legal_person_attribute_key = lpak.id and lpak.attribute_key = 'companyName'
       )
from etl.loan l
where l.country ='DE'
```

However, it returns this error:

> ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

Trying it separately, the query works.

```
select lpa.value as company_name
from etl.legal_person_attribute lpa, etl.legal_person_attribute_key lpak                            
where lpa.fk_legal_person_attribute_key = lpak.id and lpak.attribute_key = 'companyName'
```

How would you do it? Maybe using temporary tables (I don't know how to do it honestly)? Could it be a joining problem?

Thank you in advance!

More info:

The images that I put are some examples of the tables that I’m working with, just to illustrate how they are.

The query is incomple because I don’t know how to finish it.

What I would like to have is a table with the main selected columns and then, adding subqueries, I want to retrieve a columb for each value.

I've done that:

```
select l.id as loan_nr, l.country, l.currency, l.principal_amount, l.duration, l.nominal_interest_rate, l.annuity, l.payout_date, 
(select lpa.value from etl.legal_person_attribute lpa, etl.legal_person_attribute_key lpak where lpa.fk_legal_person_attribute_key = lpak.id and lpak.id = '180'
)as postcode
from etl.loan l,
etl.loan_person_role lpr,
etl.legal_person lp,
etl.legal_person_attribute lpa, 
etl.legal_person_attribute_key lpak
where l.id = lpr.loan_id and lp.id_user = lpr.fk_legal_person and lpa.fk_user = lp.id_user and lpa.fk_legal_person_attribute_key = lpak.id and 
--lpak.id = '180'and
l.profit_center='SME' and 
l.country='DE' and 
l.payout_date::DATE <= (date_trunc('month', current_date)-'1sec'::interval)::DATE
group by l.id, l.country, l.currency, l.principal_amount, l.duration, l.nominal_interest_rate, l.annuity, l.payout_date, lpa.value
limit 100
```

And still same problem. Could it be due to the fact that value column stored all data vertically and I want to extract it in different column, giving them different names according to the attribute key?

Comment: Please don't post images of tables. Use `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT INTO` statements. And your first query seems incomplete. Desired results would't harm too.

Comment: Does your separate query return only one record?

Comment: Your subquery is obviously returning more than 1 row. In such a case, which `lpa.value` of the many do you want to return?

Comment: The tables images are examples that I made in order to have an idea of what I have. My separate query returns just one column for comoany name. For lpa.value, I want to extract one column for company name, other for cities and related to the loan.